# How to skip itemWriter if readCount is zero

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have developed a batch - using spring batch , which generates file from DB.

If no matching records are found - the batch generates empty file.

I want to skip this file generation if no matching records are found.

I tried searching for help but, didn't find any threads which talk about skipping itemWriter it self.

Any help is appreciated ,
Thankyou

Comment: What have you tried so far code-wise? Care to share?

Comment: Hello,  i didn't get any leads on how can i skip itemWriter -  tried implementing it through listener - but it still can not skip itemwriter -  provided i don't want to fail my batch and i want the file generation part to be skipped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `NoWorkFoundStepExecutionListener` which is designed specifically for this use case. More details about it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#handlingStepCompletionWhenNoInputIsFound

You can also set the `shouldDeleteIfEmpty` flag on the `FlatFileItemWriter` to delete the generated file if it is empty.

Comment: i did it with shouldDeleteIfEmpty  flag  and it worked -  this was exactly what i needed , thanks a lot